# check alpha numeric password using js

Tags: javascript

I am using to js to check if the password is alphanumeric, below is the code, not sure why but it is not throwing the alert when password is not alphanumeric.

```
if (!input_string.match(/^[0-9a-z]+$/))
  {
   alert("please enter alpha numeric password")
  }
```

Comment: That is JavaScript, not PHP

Comment: The regex is OK, so your problem must be with `input_string` or `alert`. I guess it's probably with `input_string` not having the value you think it does when it's passed to your if statement..

Comment: What is the `input_string` you expect not to match?

Answer (score 0):

If your `input_string` is correct (`console.log()` to check) try to store your regex in variable and use `test()` method.

```js
let alphanumericRegex = /^[0-9a-z]+$/;

if (!alphanumericRegex.test(input_string)) {
   alert("please enter alpha numeric password");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/test